# Why AsyncTask return always the same response?

Tags: php, android, listview, android-asynctask

I have this code that makes a call to a php scripts that reply with a json. 
The json is used to be displayed as listview. 
The problem is that the following code is giving me always the same json even if those data don't exist any more in the database connected by php script.

I followed this guide
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

but I'm not able to figure out what happen a runtime.
I hope somebody can help me.

```
public class ShiftListFragment extends ListFragment {

// Progress Dialog
private static ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://www.changeshifts.netsons.org/android_connect/get_all_shifts.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_AVAILABLE_SHIFTS = "Available shifts";
private static final String TAG_IDSHIFT = "shift id";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
private static final String TAG_SHIFT = "shift";
private static final String TAG_START_LOCATION = "start location";
private static final String TAG_BEGIN = "begin";
private static final String TAG_END = "end";
private static final String TAG_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER = "identification number";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;
// Custom adapter to view list of shifts
private CustomAdapter adapter;

/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ShiftListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();



}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(productsList.get(position).get(TAG_IDSHIFT));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Shifts. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_AVAILABLE_SHIFTS);
                productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    // String idShift = c.getString(TAG_IDSHIFT);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    String shift = c.getString(TAG_SHIFT);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_START_LOCATION);
                    String begin = c.getString(TAG_BEGIN);
                    String end = c.getString(TAG_END);
                    String sn = c.getString(TAG_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    // map.put(TAG_IDSHIFT, idShift);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    map.put(TAG_SHIFT, shift);
                    map.put(TAG_START_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_BEGIN, begin);
                    map.put(TAG_END, end);
                    map.put(TAG_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER, sn);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no Shifts found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread            
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */

                adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, productsList);
                setListAdapter(adapter);


            }   

        });

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is the output of http://www.changeshifts.netsons.org/android_connect/get_all_shifts.php changing when you modify the underlying data/database?

Comment: Could you try adding `productsList.clear()` inside `onPreExecute` of your `LoadAllProducts` class?

Comment: yes the output of the php script changes, indeed, if you open the link you can see the json but in the listview I have 4 different values that are always the same and don't correspond to what I have into the database

Comment: I've tryed adding productsList.clear() inside onPreExecute but it doesn't change anything